# Dynamic array of Structs, delet elements

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a database program of students where you should be able to add/modify and delete students. I have managed to get the add function working, and also the modify function but the delete function gives me some problems. my code seems to crash when im trying to delete a student from the database, can anyone tell me where the problem lies?

Here's my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* TODO: Avoid global variables. */

struct student {
    char name[60];
    long long personalNumber;
    char gender[6];
    char studyProgram[60];
    char email[30];
    int age;
};

struct student *pointer = NULL;
int numberofstudents = 0;

void modify()
{
    long long persnr;
    long long comp;
    int match = 0;
    printf("Please enter the personal number that you wish to modify: \n");
    scanf("%lld", &persnr);
    getchar();

    for(int i = 0; i <= numberofstudents; i++)
    {
        comp = ((pointer+i)->personalNumber);
        printf("%lld\n", ((pointer+i)->personalNumber));
        printf("%lld\n", comp);


        printf("Inne");
        if (pointer[i].personalNumber == persnr && match == 0)
        {
            printf("Enter name, personalnumber, gender, studyprogram, email and age in this order\n");
            scanf("%s%lld%s%s%s%d", (pointer+i)->name, &(pointer+i)->personalNumber, (pointer+i)->gender, (pointer+i)->studyProgram, (pointer+i)->email, &(pointer+i)->age);
            match = 1;
            getchar();
        }
       if (match == 0)
       {
           printf("Could not find person");
       }

    }
}


void deletestudent()
{
    long long persnr;
    long long comp;
    int match = 0;
    printf("Please enter the personal number that you wish to delete: \n");
    scanf("%lld", &persnr);
    getchar();

    struct student *temporary = malloc((numberofstudents - 1) * sizeof(struct student));

    for(int i = 0; i <= numberofstudents; i++)
    {
        if (pointer[i].personalNumber == persnr && match == 0)
        {
            match = 1;
        }
        else if (match == 1){
            temporary[i-1] = pointer[i];
        }
        else
        {
            temporary[i] = pointer[i];
        }

       if (match == 0)
       {
           printf("Could not find person");
       }

    }
    free(pointer);
    pointer = temporary;

    }



void add(){

        if (numberofstudents > 0)
        {
            pointer = (struct student*) realloc(pointer, (numberofstudents+1) * sizeof(struct student));

            printf("Lyckades allokeringen!\n\n");
        }

        printf("Enter name, personalnumber, gender, studyprogram, email and age in this order\n");
        scanf("%s%lld%s%s%s%d", (pointer+numberofstudents)->name, &(pointer+numberofstudents)->personalNumber, (pointer+numberofstudents)->gender, (pointer+numberofstudents)->studyProgram, (pointer+numberofstudents)->email, &(pointer+numberofstudents)->age);
        getchar();
        printf("Visar data:\n");

        for(int i = 0; i <= numberofstudents; ++i)
        {
            printf("%s\t%lld\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n", (pointer+i)->name, (pointer+i)->personalNumber, (pointer+i)->gender, (pointer+i)->studyProgram, (pointer+i)->email, (pointer+i)->age);
        }
        numberofstudents = numberofstudents+1;
    }

int main(void)
{
    pointer = (struct student*) malloc(2 * sizeof(struct student));

    if (pointer == NULL)
{
    printf("pointer NULL");
    exit(1);
}

    int run = 1;
    int choice;

    while (run == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter an option listed below\n1.ADD\n2.Modify\n3.Delete\n4.Search\n5.Save\n6.Load\n7.Exit");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        getchar();

        switch(choice) {

   case 1 :
      add();
      break;

   case 2 :
      modify();
      break;
   case 3 :
      deletestudent();


   case 7 :
      exit(0);
      break;

    default :

      break;
}

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `numberofstudents` the number of elements in the array, or the top-index in the array? Because if it is the first, then all your loops will go one beyond the end and you will have *undefined behavior* as you index out of bounds.

Comment: If the `persnr` in `deletestudent()` does not exist you would copy `numberofstudents ` elements to `temporary` (+1 in fact, see @some programmer dude's comment) but that array is alloced with -1 element. Also you never decrement `numberofstudents`

Comment: You will have problems (undefined behaviour) if you enter any gender longer than five characters, such as  "female". (And using an integer type for the personal number is questionable; it's more a sequence of numerical characters (i.e. digits) than an actual number.)

Comment: It is not crashing, it is just executing `case 7:` also immediately after `case 3:`.
Add `break` statement in `case 7`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numberofstudents; i++)
```

is a huge warning sign. In C, such a loop should typically have `i < numberofstudents` in it, assuming `numberofstudents` is the actual length of the array.

Using `<=` rather than `<` makes the loop go one step too far, thus indexing outside the array and causing undefined behavior.

Writing outside heap-allocated memory and then trying to `free()` it is a good way to provoke crashes, since there's a chance you're stepping on the heap allocator's data structures (in practice; in theory all that happens is that you get undefined behavior and thus anything can happen).